# How to find coordinate of a rotated bounding box in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing

I have a rotated rectangular as

[image]

It contains the values `255` for rectangular and `0` for background. I want to find a bounding box coordinate `(x_min,x_max, y_min,y_max)` (such as red box as bellow). Could you suggest to me the way to find it in python? Thanks

[image]

This is the way how can I obtained the rotated bounding box

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform
import Image
img = np.zeros([2088,1773], dtype=np.uint8)
img[386:575, 816:1000] = 255
img =skimage.transform.rotate(img, -20, mode='edge')
img=img*255
img = Image.fromarray(img)
if img.mode != 'RGB':
    img = img.convert('RGB')
img.save("rotated_bb.jpg")
```

Comment: read [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). you didn't show code that you've already tried...

Comment: Sorry, I have updated it. Could you look at and upvote it again

Comment: yes, but what have you attempted in regards to _solving the problem?_

Comment: I have tried to find the solution but it is not success. That is reason why I ask here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np
import skimage.transform
img = np.zeros([2088,1773], dtype=np.uint8)
img[386:575, 816:1000] = 255
img = skimage.transform.rotate(img, -20, mode='edge')

rect = np.where(img==1)
xmin, xmax = rect[1].min(), rect[1].max()
ymin, ymax = rect[0].min(), rect[0].max()
```

just need to adapt it to RGB format if you really need to...

Comment: Thanks so much. But `rect = np.where(img==1)` or `rect = np.where(img==255)`? Because output of the function `skimage.transform.rotate` return value between 0 to 1

Comment: depends how your image is formatted, in the simplified version I wrote here `img.max() == 1` so I use `1`, but the logic is the same with `255` or whatever other format you want to use...